# Кнопка переключения между клавиатурой и списком смайликов

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток.

Наверняка многие видели в различных приложениях одну кнопочку, расположенную рядом с EditText'ом при отправке сообщения/комментария. Например, на [скриншоте](http://cdn9.staztic.com/app/a/952/952798/vk-messages-2657-1-s-307x512.jpg) рядом с кнопкой "Отправить" есть иконка смайлика, при нажатии на которую прячется клавиатура и появляется список доступных смайликов. Мне интересно, как вообще можно реализовать такую же вещь?

*P.S. В гугле найти мне не удалось.*

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на данную библиотеку [emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon).

Comment: Как бы сказать, у меня свой список смайликов, да и реализовать я хочу по-своему. В EditText'е мне не нужно отображение смайлика, там мне нужен его текстовый код, ибо его обрабатывать будет сервер. Да и на мой вопрос это не совсем верный ответ. Так что... нет, это не то.

Comment: Ну так добавь на экран свою таблицу, выводи туда смайлы, добавь анимации... кодом потом поделись )